# generate Classic ASP versus ASP.Net and max compability

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have some software that currently generates a series of files - one of them a relatively simple PHP file. (Not using OOP, PEAR or anything but builtin functions that exist across many PHP versions.)

I have some customers that also use ASP and ASP.Net - I never actually used any of those languages, but looking at it, I think most of the PHP code could be translated directly to classic ASP code...

However - can anyone point me to sources on how to best generate code that will execute/run on both classic ASP and new ASP.NET IIS/similar servers? Can ASP.Net execute ASP/vbscript .asp files? So if for instance I have an ASP.Net page that goes about its normal business - can that include/execute my generated classic ASP file that outputs content?

I preferably want to create a solution that is as easy as possible for me to maintain - but also as easy to use as possible by my customers.

Comment: What exactly do you want your code to do? IIS supports Classic ASP. You can run Classic ASP and ASP.net pages on the same website but they can't use each other's code

Comment: The answer is no.  They are entirely different languages that reside within different application pools that cannot reuse each others code.  **Note:** Windows 2012 supports Classic ASP, in future releases this will probably not be the case.

Comment: Currently the code is self-contained in a standalone file. Currently I only need file access to files in the same directory in itself, but it is possible I will need SQL/DB access in future. (It reads GET paramaters and returns data to AJAX/Javascript. Basicly my software generates HTML, JS, data-files and the PHP/ASP code.)